# Image Class Change Based on Time of Day

Tags: javascript, time, background, clock

Using the following script I was able to change the body background based on the time of day. However, I'd like to change it from only affecting the body, to be a class, so I can have multiple objects change their backgrounds instead of just one. Any suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('body').css('background-image', function(){

var url, hour = new Date().getHours();
if (hour > 7 && hour < 20) {
  return 'images/bg_daytime.png';
 } else {
  return 'images/bg_nighttime.png';
 }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Try;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.your_class').css('background-image', function(){
var url, hour = new Date().getHours();
if (hour > 7 && hour < 20) {
  return 'images/bg_daytime.png';
 } else {
  return 'images/bg_nighttime.png';
 }
});
</script>
```